# Get nativeElement from directive

Tags: angular

I try to get nativeElement with directive.
This is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
...

@Directive({
    selector: '[someData]',
    exportAs: 'someData'
})

export class MyDirective {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {

    }
}
```

My template looks like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let note of notes;let index;">
 ...
 <div someData #text="someData">
   ...
 </div>
 <button (click)="showNative()">click me </button>
</div>
```

And my component:

```
export class MyComponent {
 ...
  @ViewChild('data') data: any;
 ...
    showNative(): void {
        console.log( this.data );
    }
}
```

When i click the first button or the second, i see in my console just one object, it's the first nativeElement, but i need something like this:

Click the first button - i want to see the first object
Click the second button - i want to see the second object 
and etc.

I understand i have to pass ID or link in func "showNative",
but i don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to get the element of the directive, just pass the local template reference to the `showNative` call:

```
<div someData #text>
...
button (click)="showNative(text)">click me </button>

showNative(element): void {
   console.log( element );
}
```

Also if you need to get directive instances using `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` you can use the directive class like this:

```
@ViewChildren(MyDirective) children: QueryList(MyDirective);
```